# Bash script unexpected result for while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have following bash script to stop Apache server. I am not getting error but an unexpected result.

```
#!/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/httpd stop
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    exit 1
fi
RTN=10
while [[ $RTN -gt 0 ]]
echo "Before" $RTN
do
    sleep 5
    RTN=`ps -C httpd | wc -l`
    RTN=$(( RTN - 1 ))
echo "After" $RTN
done 

exit 0
```

I got the following answer which I do not expect to be, with an infinite printing:

```
Before 10
After 0

Before 0
After 0

Before 0
After 0
```

I expect to print:

```
Before 10
After -1 
#and exit here
```

Could anybody please tell me what is happening?

Comment: pmverma, it's considered bad form to change the very nature of a question after it has been answered since it renders the answers irrelevant. If the very nature changes, it should be posted as a new question, however even that's not necessary here. As shown in my answer, it was the misplacement that caused the infinite loop. If you're getting 0 as a return value, it will terminate because the condition is `gt 0`. As I also stated, _check_ the output of your `ps`, that will tell you why you're getting strange values.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I though the edited post was the original...

Comment: @Jahid, no, OP moved the `echo` inside the loop body which basically made it totally different. I gather what you were trying to do on the subsequent edit was fix the starting value of `RET` to match the actual output (10 rather than 5), and that's sensible, so I've incorporated that in the latest edit.

Comment: Thanks all guys, finally I have figured out everybody is correct. But my problem was concern to file naming of script file, which may be in someway conflicting with the (may be) `ps` command.

Comment: I will post another interesting question, I will also share link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work the way you seem to think it does:

```
while [[ $RTN -gt 0 ]]
echo "Before" $RTN
do
```

You want the `echo` to come ***after*** the `do`. With it before the `do`, it's part of the `list-1` condition rather than the `list-2` body. And, as per the `bash` docs (my bold):

> The `while` command continuously executes the list `list-2` as long as the ***last*** command in the list `list-1` returns an exit status of zero.

You can see the difference between the following script, similar to yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
RTN=2
while [[ $RTN -gt 0 ]]
echo "Before" $RTN
do
    sleep 1
    RTN=$(( RTN - 1 ))
echo "After" $RTN
done
```

which outputs (ad infinitum):

```
Before 2
After 1
Before 1
After 0
Before 0
After -1
Before -1
After -2
Before -2
```

When you move the `echo` to *inside* the body:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
RTN=2
while [[ $RTN -gt 0 ]]
do
    echo "Before" $RTN
    sleep 1
    RTN=$(( RTN - 1 ))
    echo "After" $RTN
done
```

it then terminates properly:

```
Before 2
After 1
Before 1
After 0
<returns to prompt>
```

Once that change is made, the loop terminates correctly, given the values being generated by your `ps` command.

---

Additionally, if you want to find out what's in the process list (and probably causing an result of zero rather than negative one), output the process list before checking the count:

```
:
ps -C httpd                 # Add this line temporarily.
RTN=`ps -C httpd | wc -l`
:
```

Comment: actually my problem is when I run `./stop_server.sh` it is not terminating and I have to Ctrl+t. Thus, I tried to echo and see what values are before and after. It was my fault, I put echo in wrong place.

Comment: I have updated my script according to your second one from the difference, but still not terminating. Please look at script question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ps -C httpd` command always returns a line: `PID TTY          TIME CMD` (basically the heading of the `ps` output) which is counted by `wc -l` as 1 when there is no process running. If `httpd` was running the line count would be greater than 1.

Thus `$((RTN -1))` becomes `0`.

Edit:

I notice, you have an error in your while loop:

```
while [[ $RTN -gt 0 ]]
echo "Before" $RTN
do
```

Change it to:

```
while [[ $RTN -gt 0 ]]
do
echo "Before" $RTN
```

Comment: I think at next point in lopping `RTN=$(( RTN - 1 ))` , $RTN value will be `-1` and loop will end. Am I wrong?

Comment: @pmverma In line RTN=`ps -C httpd | wc -l` it becomes 1 again and then becomes 0 by the next line

Comment: It doesnt actually matter whether it's 0 or -1 because the continuation condition is `gt 0` which is false for both those values.